# Returning an array ... rather a reference or pointer to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, return

I am a bit confused.  There are two ways to return an array from a method.  The first suggests the following:

```
typedef int arrT[10];
arrT *func(int i);
```

However, how do I capture the return which is an int (*)[]?

Another way is through a reference or pointer:

```
int (*func(int i)[10];
```

or

```
int (&func(int i)[10];
```

The return types are either int (*)[] or int (&)[].

The trouble I am having is how I can assign a variable to accept the point and I continue to get errors such as:

```
can't convert int* to int (*)[]
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong or what is lacking in my knowledge?

Comment: mismatched parentheses in your function prototypes.

Comment: you seem to be accidentally setting up function pointers. Is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: If you don't want a C++ struct, just a plain C array, then: "int* array (int* size); int size = 0; int* arr = array (&size);"

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer when you can. You should also consider acceting answers to your other questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to return an array by value, put it in a structure.

The Standard committee already did that, and thus you can use `std::array<int,10>`.

```
std::array<int,10> func(int i);
std::array<int,10> x = func(77);
```

This makes it very straightforward to return by reference also:

```
std::array<int,10>& func2(int i);
std::array<int,10>& y = func2(5);
```

Comment: I see ... I learn something everyday but specifically for my case, how do I assign a return from func to a variable?  If I use a pointer I get an error that int * does not convert to int (*)[].

Comment: can you give an example where returning a reference to non-`const` `std::array` is a good idea. i can think of only one natural usage (providing an array in a header-only module, for use throughout the program) and i don't think the OP as a beginner would understand that usage

Comment: @Alf: In `map< string, array<int,10> > m;` the return type of `m["Ben"]` is `array<int,10>&` (non-`const`).  Perhaps you want to have session-local-storage (analogous to thread-local-storage).  The accessor might return an `array<int,10>&`.  I'm sure you can think of other examples if you put your mind to it.

Comment: @Alf: Yes I think it's most useful for member functions, but the illustration with non-member is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

First, the information you give is incorrect.

You write,

> “There are two ways to return an array from a method”

and then you give as examples of the ways

```
typedef int arrT[10];
arrT *func(int i);
```

and

```
int (*func(int i))[10];
```

(I’ve added the missing right parenthesis), where you say that this latter way, in contrast to the first, is an example of

> “through a reference or pointer”

Well, these two declarations mean *exactly the same*, to wit:

```
typedef int A[10];
A* fp1( int i ) { return 0; }

int (*fp2( int i ))[10] { return 0; }

int main()
{
    int (*p1)[10]   = fp1( 100 );
    int (*p2)[10]   = fp2( 200 );
}
```

In both cases a pointer to the array is returned, and this pointer is typed as "pointer to array". Dereferencing that pointer yields the array itself, which decays to a pointer to itself again, but now typed as "pointer to item". It’s a pointer to the first item of the array. At the machine code level these two pointers are, in practice, exactly the same. Coming from a Pascal background that confused me for a long time, but the upshot is, since it’s generally impractical to carry the array size along in the type (which precludes dealing with arrays of different runtime sizes), most array handling code deals with the pointer-to-first-item instead of the pointer-to-the-whole-array.

I.e., normally such a low level C language like function would be declared as just

```
int* func()
```

return a pointer to the first item of an array of size established at run time.

Now, if you want to return an array *by value* then you have two choices:

- Returning a fixed size array by value: put it in a `struct`.
  The standard already provides a templated class that does this, **`std::array`**.
- Returning a variable size array by value: use a class that deals with copying.
  The standard already provides a templated class that does this, **`std::vector`**.

For example,

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> foo() { return vector<int>( 10 ); }

int main()
{
    vector<int> const   v = foo();
    // ...
}
```

This is the most general. Using `std::array` is more of an optimization for special cases. As a beginner, keep in mind Donald Knuth’s advice: “Premature optimization is the root of all evil.” I.e., just use `std::vector` unless there is a really really good reason to use `std::array`.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I know C++ should use vectors not arrays but in my present learning, I am learning how to return an array from a func.  Also, the first declaration is a typedef and then using the typedef.  They are not two ways to return an array.  The second listing is the second way.  This still doesn't help me understand how I can assign a variable to the return ... wow this is my question.  if I have a func defined as follows: auto func(int i) -> int (*)[10] then how do I define a variable to take the array?  THIS IS MY QUESTION!!!!!

Comment: @user633658: re "the second listing is the second way", **NO**. it means exactly the same as the first. as demonstrated above.

Comment: @user633658: re "how do I define a variable to take the array", see the complete example code given in this answer.

Comment: Yeah you are spot on ... I missed some of the reading above for your answer.  I did type int (*arr)[] and did not give it a size for the array.  May have screwed me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
using arrT10 = int[10]; // Or you can use typedef if you want

arrT10 * func(int i)
{
    arrT10 a10;
    return &a10;

    // int a[10];
    // return a;    // ERROR: can't convert int* to int (*)[]
}
```

This will give you a warning because `func` returns an address of a local variable so we should NEVER code like this but I'm sure this code can help you.